# How to fix "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function" error in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

I am working on adding the DateTimePicker to my current website.

I am using rails 6 and added jQuery in my app by yarn and I also installed a gem "datetimepicker".

Here is the form where i tried to use datetimepicker:

```
= simple_form_for @schedule do |f|
  = f.input :start_time, as: :string, input_html:{class: 'datetimepicker'}
  %br
    = f.input :end_time, as: :string, input_html:{class: 'datetimepicker'}
  %br
  %label Slot Duration
  = f.time_select :slot_duration
  .actions
  = f.submit 'Save'
:javascript
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
    });
  });
```

I was expecting on click popup a calendar with time selection but i got an error on terminal.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post the error you have ?

Comment: @xiawi here is the error i find in console "Uncaught TypeError: $(…).datetimepicker is not a function”

Comment: I have the same issue!
@Faisal Did you find the solution?